How do you access Azure App Service environment variables App Settings in Angular app?
Since you cannot access App Settings in Angular client app without using an API or an Azure Function or node.js server, are you making use of the Azure App Configuration service to centrally manage application settings.
I tried Azure App Configuration and it works. Wanted to get an idea how others are accessing the Azure App Service environment variables App Settings.
